# How to use html4 or lower version in eclipse mars?

Tags: eclipse, html, web

I am new to Eclipse and my eclipse supports html5 by default and whenever i use tag which are outdated in html5, i get an error so please help me out how to use html4 or lower version instead of html5.

Answer (score 0):

To tell the broswer you are using HTML4 documents you need to set the doctype like this in your index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

You have different DOCTYPE declarations [here](https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html).